# How do I check that my edge normals in an arbitary triangle are inward (or outward)?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, orthonormal, finite-element-method

I am considering an arbitary 2D triangle with points:

X1=(x1,y1), X2=(x2,y2), X3=(x3,y3).

I am then trying to compute the inward (or outward) normals to each edge such that they are all facing inward (or outward) but am strugling here.

Currently I have my normals by multiplying by a rotation matrix R=[0 -1;1 0] to give:

n12=R*(X1-X2)

n13=R*(X1-X3)

n32=R*(X3-X2)

but I have no idea if they are all facing inwards for an arbitary triangle.

The reason I need to keep this arbitary is so that I can compute this for multiple triangles in a mesh.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Inward or outward with respect to what? If you just have a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there's no notion of "inward" or "outward."

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey my triangles would be in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and in that case we would want the normals to be inward towards the centre of the triangle or outwards in the exterior of the triangle.

Comment: so you're trying to find vectors normal to each side of the triangle?

Comment: Yes, but i need them to be consistent so to force them to be inward for any arbitary triangle

Comment: You should clarify in the question that you are referring to the normals of the three *edges*. The standard solution is to ensure that all your triangles have a consistent orientation (typically anticlockwise in the order $X_1 \to X_2 \to X_3$); then your chosen $R$ always gives the outward normal while $-R$ gives the inward normal. Alternatively, if you cannot ensure a consistent orientation, you could compute it via the sign of $\det[X_2-X_1\quad X_3-X_2]$ (positive if anticlockwise) and then flip the normals if necessary.

Comment: @Rahul, apologies it wasn't clear. My triangles wont have consistent ordering. For your approach won't that just tell me that the normals are facing the same direction? By this you would then have may one facing inwards and one outwards? Maybe I am not understanding properly.

Comment: What I'm saying is, first compute the orientation of the triangle. If it is positive, use $-R$. If it is negative, use $R$. Then the normals will point outwards in all cases.

Comment: @Rahul They will if the differences are computed with consistent orientation: $X_1-X_2$ and $X_1-X_3$ in the question are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Rahul’s comments, before you can talk about “inward” and “outward” normals, you first have to determine where the inside and outside of the triangle lie. This is equivalent to figuring out whether traversing the vertices in numerical order corresponds to a clockwise or counterclockwise orientation of the vertices. So, examine the sign of the  determinant $$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{vmatrix}.$$ If it is positive, then the vertices are in a counterclockwise arrangement; if negative, they are clockwise. (If the determinant vanishes, then the points are colinear—the triangle is degenerate.)

You can now find inward normals via a 90-degree rotation as in your question, but to do this you need to be careful to use the same orientation for all of the difference vectors. In your question, you use $X_1-X_2$ and $X_1-X_3$, which traverse the edges of the triangle in opposite directions. If you apply the same rotation to both of these, you will end up with one inward and one outward normal no matter which direction you rotate them in. For the three edge vectors to have consistent orientation, you need to take these differences in a consistent order: $X_2-X_1$, $X_3-X_2$ and $X_1-X_3$.

Your rotation matrix represents a counterclockwise 90-degree rotation, so if the triangle is oriented counterclockwise, multiplying each of the above differences by $R$ will produce inward normals; if it’s clockwise they will be outward, and you can get inward normals by negating them. In short, $$\begin{align} n_{12} &= \operatorname{sgn}(\Delta)R(X_2-X_1) \\ n_{23} &= \operatorname{sgn}(\Delta)R(X_3-X_2) \\ n_{31} &= \operatorname{sgn}(\Delta)R(X_1-X_3) \end{align}$$ produces inward normals regardless of the order of the vertices.

Answer (score -1):

The **cross product of two vectors** produces another vector perpendicular (aka "normal") to both. The "sign" of the resulting vector swaps as you swap the order of the vectors.

Now, you get $$v12=\{x2-x1, \quad y2-y1, \quad z2-z1\}$$ and $$v13=\{x3-x1, \quad y3-y1, \quad z3-z1\}$$
The cross-product $n= v12$ x $v13$ heads to the same direction as the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) from $v12$ to $v13$. And the other normal (opposite) is $no= v13$ x $v12$

You are in a $2D$ case (set all $zi=0$), so knowing if $v12$ towards $v13$ is clockwise or counter-clockwise is easy:

$$res = (y2 - y1)·(x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1)·(y3 - y1)$$

will give a positive value if $(x3,y3)$ is at right of line $X1 \to X2$  wich means that $X1,X2,X3$ order is clockwise.

Comment: The question states quite clearly that the OP is working in two dimensions, so how is the first half of your answer relevant?