# Shortest rotation for a vector to look into a point

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose I have a camera in position $p$ whose look vector is $v$.

Given a target point $t$, I want the camera to smoothly rotate and look at $t$. How can I determine if it is faster to rotate clockwise or anti-clockwise?

[image]

In the image, clearly it's faster to rotate clockwise.

Comment: How the information is represented? For example, do you know the rectangular (=Cartesian) or polar coordinates of $t$?

Comment: Suppose it's all represented in $2D$, $p$, $v$ and $t$ are given.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question -- do you have the vectors in Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ or polar coordinates (length, angle)? Assuming they are in Cartesian coordinates, compute the determinant $\begin{vmatrix}v_x & t_x \\ v_y & t_y\end{vmatrix} = v_xt_y - v_yt_x$ and check its sign. If it's positive, rotate anticlockwise, if negative rotate clockwise.

Comment: All cartesian coordinates, e.g.: $p = (0,1), v = (0.8, 0.6), t = (-1, 3.3)$.

Comment: @Rahul That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @amd: It only became an answer after the OP clarified their question in the following comment. It's also an *incorrect* answer, seeing as $p$ is nonzero. Feel free to post a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Vector camera to current target = $\;\vec v$

Vector camera to new target = $\;\vec t$

The cross product $\;\vec v \times \vec t= \vec r\;$ gives the axis of rotation.

The module of this product $\;\lvert \vec r \rvert = \lvert \vec v \rvert · \lvert \vec t \rvert · sin \theta \;$ gives the angle $\theta\;$ of rotation from $\vec v\;$ to $\vec t\;$. This angle is always $\le 180º$.

In 2D, to tell the clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3291142/688039)

Comment: Note the question is how to decide if it should rotate clockwise or anti-clockwise, not to measure the angle.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I knew. I was searching for an existing answer. Now edited.